# Outlook accounts not showing in the Accounts setting page

Tags: email, accounts, outlook, active-sync

A user came to me with an intermittent issue with his old handset. I replaced the handset but when it came to set up his outlook account the app wouldn't sync contacts as the option to sync contacts was missing from the outlook app. Everything else worked but that. I checked in the accounts page in settings and the account isn't displayed there. I re-installed the application and updated the phone but to no avail. I then tried adding the account in the accounts screen, the account was added no problem but still the account isn't showing in on that page. I try to re-add for the 3rd time and this time an error message pops up telling me that the account has already been added to this device. I then tried to set up the old device as I know that it was working on there before I set up the new device. Again the same issue occurs.

Does anyone else have this issue with outlook on android or any other email application on android?

As a last resort I have set up exchange activesync using the default email application but I would like to have the user back on outlook as all the support material we have references Outlook Android.

-Rezz

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen and it was driving me nuts. I did finally solve it by deleting the Exchange account from the Outlook app, going to the Accounts menu and hitting Add Account, adding the Exchange Activesync account. THEN, go back to Outlook and add the account again. Outlook walked me through the entire process of adding the account, even though it theoretically existed. Having essentially added the same account both ways, though, it now shows up in the Accounts page and works in the Outlook app.